# Importing existing pdf into new document

Tags: itext

I am trying to use iTextSharp to build a new pdf document, that will contain some already existing pdf's. I can import existing jpg's without a problem, but i am struggling with pdfs. Anyone got any info to point me in the right direction

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to append PDFs to an existing PDF?  If so, check out the class here:

http://www.wacdesigns.com/2008/10/03/merge-pdf-files-using-c/

You'll need to spend a little time correcting minor errors, but otherwise the class is working fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

For info i managed to use iTextShape in the end, if anyone would like some info i will be happy to post it